# Charged checked baggages for connecting international flights

Tags: luggage, fees-and-charges, american-airlines, taipei

I was traveling from Dfw-SFO (AA) and SFO- Taipei (Eva Air)
I brought 2 suitcases and AA charged me $60.
Has this ever happens to anyone?
Their reasoning was that Eva Air is not part of One World.

Answer (score 1):

Checked baggage rules depends on the purchased ticket and eventually to a frequent-flyer program status of the passenger.

Let's say for example that you purchased a single ticket from Dallas to Taipei economic class with a single checked baggage. Because you have the status X of the frequent-flyer program Y and the company that is serving your single ticket recognize the frequent-flyer program they give you an extra checked baggage for free valid for all the trip.

Another example: you bought two separate tickets, one from Dallas to San Francisco and another from San Francisco to Taipei (economy class and 1 checked baggage allowed). In this case only the flight from Dallas to San Francisco is served by a company that recognize your frequent-flyer status and give you the extra checked baggage only for that part of your trip.

Comment: U.S. law requires the whole itinerary (bought under one ticket) be treated consistently: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/399.87

Comment: and as I wrote in my example, we don't know if he bought a single ticket or two separated tickets

Comment: Even if it were on a single ticket, the "most significant" carrier rule may have been applied, which makes the second suitcase to be paid for consistently for the whole journey.